# chef windows_package encoding errors

Tags: ruby, encoding, chef-infra

I am trying to use Chef to install R onto windows 7.

I installed `chef_handler` and `windows` using `knife`

`knife cookbook site install windows`
`knife cookbook site install chef_handler`

and created a new cookbook

`chef generate cookbook cookbooks/awesome_machine_config`

inside `default.rb` I have

```
windows_package 'R for Windows 3.3.2' do
  source 'd:/Downloads/R-3.3.2-win.exe'
  action :install
end
```

inside `metadata.rb`
I have:

```
depends 'windows'
```

when I run:

```
chef-client --local-mode recipe[awesome_machine_config]
```

It synchronises the cookbooks fine and installs the cookbook gems fine.
But then I get a:

```
Error executing action `install` on resource 'windows_package[R for Windows 3.3.2]'

Encoding::InvalidByteSequenceError
incomplete "\x00" on UTF-16LE
```

chef is running as administrator so shouldn' be a permissions fault?
Any ideas how to debug?

Comment: For start, you can try to run chef-client in debug mode `-l debug`.

Comment: Is you R installer download not corrupted ? (and you may need `installer_type :custom` and giving R installer the proper switches for a silent install)

Comment: The installer is no corrupt and the error occurs at `windows_package 'R for Windows 3.3.2' do ` statement according to the error message

Comment: No it doesn't occur at the statement, it occurs during the converge phase of the windows_package provider, run chef with `-l debug` to see what's happening as command line. But the error you're getting sounds really coming from the NSIS installer on CRCcheck.